# 2 and 3 standard deviation formula

Tags: formula, powerbi, standard-deviation

I am trying to get 2 and 3 standard deviations on both sides of the mean.

I can use the STDEV formula to get the standard deviation:

```
STDEV.P(Sheet1[Residual])
```

However, how can I get 2 or 3 standard deviation out? I'm a bit confused how to go about this as it is multiplying the total twice and not the standard deviation.

```
STDEV.P(Sheet1[Residual])*2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding

> I'm a bit confused how to go about this as it is multiplying the total
>   twice and not the standard deviation.

I have to say I'm a bit confused too. This can be easily done with the simplest of measures, but I may be missing your point somehow. Are you perhaps really looking for the mean +/- 1 and 2 standard deviations for a *rolling* period? If **not**, you can do what you're asking for with simple measures likes this:

**1.** `mean = AVERAGE(Sheet1[Residual])`

**2.** `sigma = STDEV.P(Sheet1[Residual])`

**3.** `mean + 2 sigma = [mean] + [sigma]*2`

**4.** `mean + 1 sigma = [mean] + [sigma]`

**5.** `mean - 1 sigma = [mean] - [sigma]`

**6.** `mean - 2 sigma = [mean] - [sigma]*2`

So with a dataset like this:

```
Date,Residual
26.09.2018,15
27.09.2018,17
28.09.2018,14
29.09.2018,14
30.09.2018,20
01.10.2018,11
02.10.2018,19
03.10.2018,19
04.10.2018,18
```

You can set up a table like this:

[image]

And add a multi-row card with those exact measures like this:

[image]